# MPMoviePlayer doesn't work in app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsbundle

I am trying to create an app with my video to play in a view with a UIButton. FYI: I am using a storyboard with a tab bar view controller, so this code MPMoviePlayerView is inside another view.

I keep getting this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Here is my code:

**VideoTefViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VideoTefViewController : UIViewController


-(IBAction)playMovie;
@end
```

**VideoTefViewController.m**

```
#import "VideoTefViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface VideoTefViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoTefViewController

-(IBAction)playMovie {

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"tef" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie play];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the argument to fileURLWithPath: is nil, so for some reason moviePath is nil.  Are you sure you have a file called tef.mp4 in your bundle?

Comment: I am sure I have a file called tef.mp4 in my project. It is in my Supporting Files/Resources Files folder in xcode. Should I put somewhere else?

Comment: @YuvalMarcus, try logging moviePath right after the line where you create it and see if it's nil.

Comment: So should I write: NSlog what?

Comment: Sorry that was a stupid question, I get this: MoviePath is: /Users/ymarcus/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/A63749A0-0B7A-4E1C-93A5-93F20C89AB0D/SephardiJews.app/Tefillin.mp4, So I am guessing it is not nil

Comment: I thought you said the file was tef.mp4?, but no matter, it's obviously not nil.  I don't know what to say -- I pasted your code into an app, added an mp4 file and renamed it tef, and it worked fine.  Do you have somewhere else in your code where you call initFileURLWithPath: or fileURLWithPath: ?

Comment: No, there is nowhere else I call initFileURLWithPath or fileURLWithPath. Now, for some reason, the button doesn't give me an error and doesn't do anything, it just highlights blue for a few seconds, and I know the button is connected. I'm so confused!